# AngularJs how to access Model Attribute value from Spring MVC controller

Tags: java, angularjs, spring-mvc

I have a Spring MVC Controller returning a page with an attribute as followed

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/create")
public ModelAndView getAddAccountView() {
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("protected/accounts/AccountAddView");
    List<Client> clients=clientService.findAll();
    model.addObject("listClients", clients);
    return model;
}
```

Client is a @Entity

in my AccountAddView.jsp file, i'm trying to use the ng-init as follow:

```
<div class="row-fluid" ng-controller="accountsController as ctrl" ng-init="clients=${listClients}">
```

and in my app.js, in my controller, i try to access the list of client as followed

```
var listOfClients=$scope.clients;
```

but I'm still getting the following error

```
angular.min-1.5.3.js:116 Error: [$parse:lexerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.3/$parse/lexerr?p0=Unexpected%20nextharacter%20&p1=s%2033-33%20%5B%40%5D&p2=clients%3D%5Bsoftbank.ui.model.Client%4042%2C%softbank.ui.model.Client%4041%2C%softbank.ui.model.Client%4043%5D
at Error (native)
at http://localhost:8080/softbank/resources/js/angular.min-1.5.3.js:6:416
at gc.throwError (http://localhost:8080/softbank/resources/js/angular.min-1.5.3.js:212:149)
at gc.lex (http://localhost:8080/softbank/resources/js/angular.min-1.5.3.js:211:16)
at Object.ast (http://localhost:8080/softbank/resources/js/angular.min-1.5.3.js:216:103)
at Object.compile (http://localhost:8080/softbank/resources/js/angular.min-1.5.3.js:225:232)
at hc.parse (http://localhost:8080/softbank/resources/js/angular.min-1.5.3.js:252:380)
at e (http://localhost:8080/softbank/resources/js/angular.min-1.5.3.js:123:317)
at m.$eval (http://localhost:8080/softbank/resources/js/angular.min-1.5.3.js:142:463)
at pre (http://localhost:8080/softbank/resources/js/angular.min-1.5.3.js:271:500)
```

please what is wrong here. why is ng-init generating this errors? 
thanks in advance for your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm just starting with Angular with Spring so what I'll do is explain how I did it and you can see if it's a viable option for you.

For one, I didn't try to go through the `ModelAndView` for my data. I let my "regular" controller return the view but got my data via the angular controller and service along with a `@RestController` on the Spring side (that's two separate Spring controllers then).

To return only the view you have at least two options that I'm aware of. One, you can just return a [`ModelAndView`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/ModelAndView.html) without a model like so:

```
public ModelAndView yourView() {
    return new ModelAndView("yourView");
}
```

Or two, return the name of the view as a string like so:

```
public String yourView() {
    return "yourView";
}
```

In both cases you'd obviously need the correct `@RequestMapping`.

In my view I had an angular controller function that made a call to my associated angular service which in turn called my `@RestController` and so on. I initiated the data like so:

`ng-controller="MyController as ctrl" ng-init="ctrl.allThings()"`

Examples of the code:

Angular controller:

```
self.allThings = function () {
        ThingService.things()
            .then(
                function (data) {
                    self.things = data;
                },
                function (errResponse) {
                    console.error("Error retrieving thing list");
                }
            );
    };
```

Angular service:

```
    things: function() {
        return $http.get('/things')
            .then(
                function(response) {
                    return response.data;
                },
                function (errResponse) {
                    return $q.reject(errResponse);
                }
            );
    },
```

Spring REST controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/things", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List<Thing> things() {
    return thingService.findAll();
}
```

I imagine you know the remaining code for the Spring side. Jackson will handle all the object conversions for you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But there is something that I'm not understanding. When do you request your view from spring controller? Can you show me, please your spring controller side that return your view?

Comment: @blaiso, you're welcome. Please see the edit; I've added a couple controller options.

Comment: Thanks so much  ChiefTwoPencils. I used your strategy and it works fine for me

Answer (score 3):

Old Post but still I would like to answer so that anyone who is using Angular with Spring MVC get some help.
Using model attribute is a challenge with Angular. Earlier I was setting employee data in model attribute like `mav.addObject("employee",employee)`, but when I was trying to use `${employee}` inside the jsp, Angular wasn't able to set the java object using `ng-init` directive because it was expecting a java script object. So I set json inside the model Attribute `mav.addObject("employeeJson", empJson)` and parsed it using `json.Parse()` to convert it into Java Script Object and was able to use it with Angular expressions on the jsp
 Below are the steps which I followed:
**1. Spring Controller**
In your controller, set json in the model attribute. For e.g.
`mav.addObject("employeeJson", empJson);`
Make sure before adding it to `ModelAttribute`, replace quotes with html entity " otherwise there will be error while parsing the json
`empJson.replaceAll("\"", "\&\quot;");`
**2. Jsp**
Use angular init directive, `data-ng-init="yourController.getEmployeeData('${employeeJson}')"`
**3. In Angular js**
 parse this json to get the json 
`var vm = this;`
`vm.employee = {};`
`vm.getEmployeeData = function(employeeJson){,
    vm.employee = JSON.parse(employeeJson);
};`
**4. Inside jsp**
I can access employee name as
`{{yourController.employee.firstName}}`

Comment: The reason for this is the .jsp is a server-side template while angular runs in the browser. The jsp code is rendered on the server, replacing your `${employeeJson}` with the actual json string. When angular runs the init it now has the actual string value hard coded into the html. This is a long way around achieving what would be possible with returning json data directly to the front-end.

Comment: When I make ajax call and return json from server, the receiving end i.e. js parse this json successfully but initially while I was loading the jsp, my .js needs this json and to supply json which I set in model attribute, I took this approach.